# Laravel dockerizado no consigo conectar a MySQL

Tags: php, laravel, docker, laravel-6, docker-compose

tengo un proyecto con Windows+Docker donde quiero instalar laravel, el cual funciona con Apache y Mysql pero este último por el puerto 3307, los dockers los tengo abiertos y funcionando y desde el workbench de mysql me conecto a la ip 127.0.0.1 por el puerto 3307 y veo las tablas y los datos correctamente.

El problema lo tengo al intentar conectar desde el propio laravel, creo que el problema está en el archivo .env file para acceder a la variable de sistema del host de mysql, para ello tengo estos ficheros

**Docker compose**

```
version: '3.7'
services:
  app:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: .docker/Dockerfile
    image: laravelapp
    command: php artisan serve --host 0.0.0.0 --port=8080
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    environment:
      - SQL_HOST=db
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www/html
  db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 3307:3306
    environment:
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=laraapp_db
      - MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD=1
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=
      - MYSQL_HOST=
    volumes:
      - mysql_data:/var/lib/mysql

volumes:
    mysql_data:
```

Y luego el archivo .env lo tengo de esta manera

```
APP_NAME=Laravel
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=XXXXXXXXXXXXXX
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_URL=http://localhost:8080

LOG_CHANNEL=stack

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST="${SQL_HOST}"
DB_PORT=3307
DB_DATABASE=laraapp_db
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=
```

He probado a conectarme como digo por el puerto 3307 y me conecta a la mysql que tengo en el docker.
He probado a conectarme al docker donde tengo laravel y ejecutar las migraciones con el comando "php artisan migrate" y me genera las tablas correctamente.
El problema lo tengo al acceder desde el laravel a mysql, con una URl tipo  http://localhost:8080/api/users

El error que recibo es este

```
Illuminate\Database\QueryException
SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused (SQL: select * from `users`)
http://localhost:8080/api/users
```

Comment: En tu `DB_PORT` no deberías tener 3306?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El host del contenedor sql desde docker sería el nombre del contenedor, es decir prueba con **db** o añadele un nombre de contenedor y utiliza ese